# What are the white spots on the trunk of my orange and grapefruit trees?

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, citrus

I have white spots on the trunk of my orange and grapefruit trees, and I don't know what that means. I live in Houston, Texas. The spots on the trunk differ from the spots on the leaves. I do not see them described on the internet or in USDA articles.

Comment: We need a photo please

Comment: Agree. first thing that comes to mind is Cottony cushion scales, but It's a guessing game without pictures

Comment: @pnuts plus 3 apparently now, someone must have downvoted, but this is a new member - he needs rep to post more than one picture, and it sounds like it might be an interesting/useful to others question. Also for encouragement

Comment: @pnuts well, each to his own - I voted up before anyone else did so he could add plenty of images if he wanted to, if he doesn't, he doesn't, in which case, the question is, as you say, not informative for other people.